# Replace numbers in a string

Tags: c#-4.0

I Have some text file. theses  texts contain a string like this(a part of text):

```
<abbr class="word p1"">dd</abbr>
<img src"D:\Images\1.png">
<abbr class="word p1">dd</abbr>
<img src"D:\ticket\t\1.png">
```

In each text file,(`D:\Images\1.png) png` name is different but it is always numbers(from 1 to 114)for example(1,2,3,10,...)

I want to replace this text `D:\Images\[number].png` with a specific text for expample:

```
string newtext=Replace("D:\Images\[number].png","Something");
```

How can i do this?
thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular expression:

```
string newtext = Regex.Replace(text, @"(D:\\Images\\)\d+(.png)","$1Something$2");
```

It will replace the full match, including `D:\Images\` and `.png`, so `$1` and `$2` puts back what's caught by the parentheses, so that `Somthing` only replaces the digits.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions that are represented mostly be the *Regex* class. See these links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93804/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-C-NET

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Link only answers are not very good - if you could summarize or even _give_ the answer directly, so much better.